# MySQL / vb.NET: Check exisiting data before run the insert query

Tags: mysql, vb.net, api

I'm using vb.net to create API (MySQL). I know how to run create API for insert, select, and update. Now, I want to create an API that before data insert, must check the data, either exist in the table or not. If exist, then cannot insert the data. Below is my current vb.net code:

```
            <WebMethod()>
            <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False, XmlSerializeString:=False)>
            Public Sub TGWL_insertLoadingSV(bl_id As String, cont_size_id As String, straping As String)
                Dim mySQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=" & l_DB_SERVER & ";Initial Catalog=" & l_DB_NAME & ";User Id=" & l_DB_USER & ";Password=" & l_DB_PASS)
                Dim myDataAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
                Dim myDataset As DataSet = New DataSet
                Dim myJson As String = ""

                Try
                    If bl_id.Length > 0 Or cont_size_id.Length > 0 Or straping.Length > 0  Then

                        Dim myResponse As New failResponceClass

                        myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
                        myDataAdapter.InsertCommand = New MySqlCommand("BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO wla_loading_sv (bl_id, cont_size_id) 
        VALUES ('" & bl_id & "', '" & cont_size_id & "');
        INSERT INTO wla_special_req (bl_id, straping) 
        VALUES('" & bl_id & "', '" & straping & "');
        COMMIT;")

                        myDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Connection = mySQLConnection
                        mySQLConnection.Open()
                        myDataAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        mySQLConnection.Close()

                        myResponse.statusCode = 1
                        myResponse.errCode = ""
                        myResponse.title = l_Title_TGWLAppUser
                        myResponse.desc = "TGWL App User"

                        Me.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                        Me.Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResponse))

                    Else
                        Dim myFailedResponce As New failResponceClass

                        myFailedResponce.statusCode = 0
                        myFailedResponce.errCode = "R01"
                        myFailedResponce.title = l_Title_TGWLAppUser
                        myFailedResponce.desc = "Missing parmeter."

                        Me.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                        Me.Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFailedResponce))
                    End If

                Catch ex As SoapException
                    Throw ex
                Finally
                    MySqlConnection.ClearPool(mySQLConnection)
                    MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
                    mySQLConnection.Close()
                    mySQLConnection.Dispose()
                End Try

            End Sub
```

Thus, how do I want to make sure that the bl_id does not exist at wla_loading_sv table? I want to make it in one API. Can someone help?

Comment: Why are you creating a data adapter there? The whole point of a data adapter is to call `Fill` and `Update` with a `DataTable`. If you're not doing that then don't create a useless data adapter.

Comment: You should also learn how to use parameters with ADO.NET. Using string concatenation to insert values into SQL code has all sorts of issues.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be writing a transaction into the SQL code. Transactions are built into ADO.NET. What you should be doing is using a single connection and two commands. Begin a transaction on the connection, execute the two commands and then commit the transaction, or roll it back if there's an exception.

Comment: As for the question, you can either query the table first and then only insert if the result set is empty, or you can build the check into the command that does the insert. I don't use MySQL much at all so I don't know the syntax but, in SQL Server, you can use `IF EXISTS` to do that check. I suggest you look for something similar in MySQL, if you prefer to go that way.